# Usando jQuery Validation Engine e validação de CNPJ

Tags: jquery, validação

Eu estou usando o jQuery Validation Engine com [este arquivo](https://code.google.com/p/jqwicket/source/browse/trunk/jqwicket/src/main/java/net/javaforge/jqwicket/ui/validationengine/jquery.validationEngine-pt.js?r=298) de traduções para Português. Adicionei no JavaScript a seguinte linha:

```
"cnpj": {
    "regex": /^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\-\d{2}$/,
     "alertText": "* CNPJ inválido"
 }
```

No ASPX utilizo:

```
asp:TextBox ID="txtCNPJ" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required,custom[cnpj]]
```

Porém esta validação não é muito eficiente, já que só verifica a quantidade de caracteres.

Como posso fazer um método para validar o CNPJ e continuar utilizando o Validation Engine desta forma?

Comment: O que é "CNPJ " ?

Comment: @Sergio É um documento referente ao cadastro nacional de empresas aqui do Brasil: "Cadastro Nacional de Pessoa Jurídica". O número de cada CNPJ é no formato do regex da pergunta e os dois últimos são dígitos verificadores.

Comment: @utluiz, aha. Acho-me meio desqualificado :P Mas já agora, existe um padrão? ordem de letras (e quais), numeros, pontos? É baseado no nome ou gerado pelo estado?

Comment: @Sergio A [Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_Nacional_da_Pessoa_Jur%C3%ADdica) tem tudo.

Comment: @utluiz boa! +1 para a wikipédia :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue a solução correta:

Colocar no aspx

```
asp:TextBox ID="txtCNPJ" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required, funcCall[validateCNPJ]]"
```

Colocar no jquery.validationEngine-pt_BR.js

```
"cnpj": {
          "alertText": "* CNPJ inválido"
       }
```

Colocar no Javascript

```
function validateCNPJ(field, rules, i, options) {
    var valido = isCNPJValid(field.val()); //implementar a validação
    if (!valido) {
        //internacionalização
        return options.allrules.cnpj.alertText;
    }
}

function isCNPJValid(cnpj) {
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
    if (cnpj == '') return false;
    if (cnpj.length != 14)
        return false;
    // Elimina CNPJs invalidos conhecidos
    if (cnpj == "00000000000000" ||
        cnpj == "11111111111111" ||
        cnpj == "22222222222222" ||
        cnpj == "33333333333333" ||
        cnpj == "44444444444444" ||
        cnpj == "55555555555555" ||
        cnpj == "66666666666666" ||
        cnpj == "77777777777777" ||
        cnpj == "88888888888888" ||
        cnpj == "99999999999999")
        return false;

    // Valida DVs
    tamanho = cnpj.length - 2
    numeros = cnpj.substring(0, tamanho);
    digitos = cnpj.substring(tamanho);
    soma = 0;
    pos = tamanho - 7;
    for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
        soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
        if (pos < 2)
            pos = 9;
    }
    resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
    if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0))
        return false;

    tamanho = tamanho + 1;
    numeros = cnpj.substring(0, tamanho);
    soma = 0;
    pos = tamanho - 7;
    for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
        soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
        if (pos < 2)
            pos = 9;
    }
    resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
    if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Analisando a documentação, encontrei O [`funcCall[methodName]`](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#validators/funccall-methodname), que permite chamar uma função customizada para fazer a validação.

Segue um exemplo baseado na documentação:

```js
function verificaCNPJ(field, rules, i, options){
    var valido = isCNPJValid(field.val()); //implementar a validação
    if (!valido) {
        //internacionalização
        return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
    }
}
```

O html deveria ficar assim:

```html
<input value="" class="validate[required,funcCall[verificaCNPJ]]" type="text" id="cnpj" name="cnpj" />
```

Para implementar a função do CNPJ você pode usar o exemplo da [Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_Nacional_da_Pessoa_Jur%C3%ADdica):

```js
function isCNPJValid() {  
    var b = [6,5,4,3,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2], c = this;
    if((c = c.replace(/[^\d]/g,"").split("")).length != 14)
        return false;
    for (var i = 0, n = 0; i < 12; n += c[i] * b[++i]); 
    if(c[12] != (((n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - n))
        return false; 
    for (var i = 0, n = 0; i <= 12; n += c[i] * b[i++]); 
    if(c[13] != (((n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - n))
        return false; 
    return true; 
};
```

Comment: Acho que não deu muito certo

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha  Qual parte?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem uma boa explicação sobre validação de CNPJ, você pode realizar ela tanto no front quanto no backend.

http://www.macoratti.net/alg_cnpj.htm

Comment: Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia
o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter 
conteúdo aqui mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta;  
você poderia fazer isso?
Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! 
Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: 
[Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)